# transaction underpriced error occured whever i tried to run the below code

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

```
const tx = {
    nonce: 5,
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    to: null,
    value: 0,
    data: "0x608060405234801561001057600",
    chainId: 1337,
  };
  // const signedTxResponse = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
  const sentTxResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
  // await sentTxResponse.wait(1);
  console.log("sentTxResponse", sentTxResponse);
```

i have an error for the above code its give me an transaction underpriced error  error: could not coalesce error

```
(error={ "code": -32003, "message": "transaction underpriced", "stack": "Error: transaction underpriced\\n    at shouldReplace (/tmp/.mount_ganach8fQ6uV/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:119740)\\n    at TransactionPool.prepareTransaction (/tmp/.mount_ganach8fQ6uV/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:122311)" }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.4.0)
```

i tried to change the gas limit and gas price

Comment: Do you think is this a good and understandable question?

Comment: sorry for that its my first time for writing question on stack overflow

Comment: the error speaks for itself - the gas price in the transaction is too low to be accepted by the network

Comment: so how can i solve it

Comment: i gave the exact amount in the ganache-cli gas price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const nonce = await wallet.getNonce()
    const tx = {
        nonce: nonce,
        gasPrice: 20000000000,
        gasLimit: 1000000,
        to: null,
        value: 0,
        data: "0x608060405234801561001057600",
        chainId: 1337,
      };
   // const signedTxResponse = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
   const sentTxResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
   // await sentTxResponse.wait(1);
   console.log("sentTxResponse", sentTxResponse);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).